# conversion of date and time into another format in full calendar

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

I am working ion full calendar in c# MVC .a need to read dates from database .but I can't read them in proper mode  by using JSON thus I need to convert dates to following format...

Current Output Format:2014-06-01 16:00

```
[{"id":"d719381c-b3e4-e311-afa9-eca86bf6cf86","title":"Annual Function","start":"2014-06-01 16:00","end":"2014-06-01 19:00"},{"id":"d719381c-b3e4-e311-afa9-eca86bf6cf86","title":"convocation day","start":"2014-06-24 00:49 12:49","end":"2014-06-24 "}]
```

Required output Format : "/Date(1423087200000)/"

```
[{"id":1259,"title":"bvbvcbc","start":"/Date(1423845000000)/","end":"/Date(1423931400000)/","allDay":false,"description":"Notesbvbvcbc"},{"id":1263,"title":"om nmh sivaay ","start":"/Date(1423087200000)/","end":"/Date(1423432800000)/","allDay":false,"description":"Notesom nmh sivaay "},{"id":1265,"title":"vimal raturi","start":"/Date(1423546200000)/","end":"/Date(1423632600000)/","allDay":false,"description":"Notesvimal raturi"}
```

Comment: What format is that? unix timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answers,

i found the answer by simply writin g following code in my view under the ajax success property,

```
  $.each(data, function (i, item)
                        {
                            item.start = new Date(item.start);
                            item.end = new Date(item.end);
                      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use `Date()` method to get the unix timestamp.

```
var ob = [
    {"id":"d719381c-b3e4-e311-afa9-eca86bf6cf86","title":"Annual Function","start":"2014-06-01 16:00","end":"2014-06-01 19:00"},
    {"id":"d719381c-b3e4-e311-afa9-eca86bf6cf86","title":"convocation day","start":"2014-06-24 00:49","end":"2014-06-24 12:49"}
];

for (var i = 0; i < ob.length; i++ ){
    var unix_start = new Date(ob[i].start);
    var unix_end = new Date(ob[i].end);
    ob[i].start = '/Date(' + unix_start.getTime() /1000 + ')/';
    ob[i].end = '/Date(' + unix_end.getTime() /1000 + ')/';
}
```